# Bootstrap carousel goes missing on smartphones

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've built a carousel with bootstrap following some tutorials. 
It works fine on my laptop's screen, even when I resize the window, but once I open it on my smartphone, the carousel goes missing and all I see are the indicator arrows plus the image alt text.

The code is pretty standard but here it goes:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                  <img src="http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2016/03/29/beautiful-nature-wallpaper_042325903_304.jpg" alt="portfolio1">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Portfolio1</h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2016/03/29/beautiful-nature-wallpaper_042325903_304.jpg" alt="portfolio1">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Portfolio2</h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2016/03/29/beautiful-nature-wallpaper_042325903_304.jpg" alt="portfolio1">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Portfolio3</h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Is there another class the tutorials forgot to mention or do I need to do some work on CSS? Hope you can help me.

Much appreciated

Comment: Can you add the rest of the carousel code?

Comment: This is all the carousel code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added link of jquery.min file?
or give link of the website

Comment: I don't have one. I'm pretty new to this and the tutorials I watched never mentioned jquery.

Comment: add this in your header
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: My bad, I'm just realising what you meant. Yes, I have this on my head:

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest bootstrap 4 beta then you need to replace "item" with "carousel-item".

Here's your code merged with the example carousel here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-indicators

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2016/03/29/beautiful-nature-wallpaper_042325903_304.jpg" alt="portfolio1">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Portfolio1</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2016/03/29/beautiful-nature-wallpaper_042325903_304.jpg" alt="portfolio1">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Portfolio2</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2016/03/29/beautiful-nature-wallpaper_042325903_304.jpg" alt="portfolio1">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Portfolio3</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Example codepen https://codepen.io/Washable/pen/pWXXje

Comment: I'm using 3.3.7 on Codepen. The carousel-item class doesn't seem to be working. When I add it, the 3 slides just get stacked.

Comment: @JoelMonteiro Your question is tagged with bootstrap 4. Code is not interchangeable between the two versions.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's my fault. This is literally my first post on Stackoverflow and I missed that.